# Javascript: How to parse data from this string

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

I have the following string returned from a server:

```
{"href":"about:blank#&executeFunction<-finishedStroke&&arguments<-{\"base64DataUrl\":\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAErkJggg==\"}&"}
```

I want to extract `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAErkJggg==` (the base64DataURL part) from it. What's the best way to do this with Javascript?

Please note that I am asking how to parse values from JSON. This is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json), which asks how to extract fields from nested objects and arrays.

**What I've tried:** I have tried

```js
JSON.parse(<string>).href.split('base64DataUrl":"')[1].split('"')[0]
```

which yields the right answer, but I'm hoping for a more concise solution.

Comment: @Phil Do you know if there's a way for me to remove the duplicate tag? I edited the question to specify that it's not the same as the other question, but the duplicate tag is still there.

Comment: It's not really enough to only say _"this is not the same"_. You should also explain why. In any case, I've re-opened this but you should still provide an explanation. And while you're editing your question, you should also show what you've tried

Comment: So wait, your one-line solution works but you're after something better? I'm really failing to see why this is a question

Comment: That's right, even though my solution is one line, I'm interested to know if there's a solution that doesn't have as many chained functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* JSON, but the part you're interested in isn't exposed as part of the object. So I would suggest that you just consider it a string and use a string-parsing method, like a regular expression.

```js
const string = `{"href":"about:blank#&executeFunction<-finishedStroke&&arguments<-{\"base64DataUrl\":\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAErkJggg==\"}&"}`;

const dataURL = /"base64DataUrl":"(.*?(?="))/gm.exec(string)[1];
console.log(dataURL);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification about what's exposed as part of the object. The regex works!

Answer (score 1):

Since the server is not returning valid JSON, you will have to parse it with `indexOf` and `substring`.

```
let y = stringFromServer; 
let a = y.indexOf('data:'); 
let b = y.indexOf('\"}',a); 
let dataUrl = y.substring(a,b);
```

Comment: Or use a regex as suggested by @matthew-e-brown

Comment: In what way is it not valid JSON?

Comment: When I threw it into `JSON.parse`, I got the error `1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 68`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try

```js
let sample = {"href":"about:blank#&executeFunction<-finishedStroke&&arguments<-{\"base64DataUrl\":\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAErkJggg==\"}&"}

let splitter = sample.href.split("<-")

console.log(JSON.parse(splitter[2].substring(0, splitter[2].length - 1))["base64DataUrl"]
)
```

Comment: This does work, and is similar to my initial attempt. Thanks!